# All links redirecting to homepage

Tags: redirect

All the link on my website redirects to homepage with this text after the domain name `/?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2F%20%2F%20%2F`

So is `/cart` `/checkout`

Domain name is nikah.io

I have tried changing the permalink setting if I set it to plain I get the error page not found for `%postname%` this is the error I get.

Comment: Update permalink structure from wp-admin setting, then try to open link

Comment: @sarafrajkazi He already did since he states he changed the permalink settings.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had the default theme installed with these plugins, Thrive Architect and Ultimate Members. I raised a support ticket with Thrive Architect forums to which I received a reply the reply that when Ultimate Member plugin was disabled everything was working fine.

I further dig into that and came across a stupid configuration error on my part here Dashboard > Ultimate Members > Settings > Access (tab) > Global Site Access I had selected Site Accessible to logged in members only and set the redirect to home page.

I fixed it and it started working properly.